# Checking for null element in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to check whether an Array element is null.

I have initialized an array of `String` which has a size of 2. I looped through the array and check whether an array element is null. If it's null, I will add a `String` "a" to that position only.

My codes below will produce the following output:

```
1=a
2=a
```

Code:

```
public class CheckArrayElementIsNull {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[2];       
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] == null) {
                arr[i] = "a";
            }
            System.out.println(i + "=" + arr[i]);   
            if(arr[i] == null) {
                System.out.println(i + "= null");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add a break after my if condition but is not printing out anything.

```
 public class CheckArrayElementIsNull {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[2];       
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] == null) {
                arr[i] = "a"; 
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(i + "=" + arr[i]);   
            if(arr[i] == null) {
                System.out.println(i + "= null");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected this output:

```
1=a
2=null
```

Comment: You should check and print the null value before you assign to it, otherwise that element won't be null when you check it the second time.

Comment: Why are you starting from 1 rather than 0?

Comment: ok maybe I should start it with 0. sorry.edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `break` will break the iteration of the `for` loop, and exit out of loop immediately. You should change your design a bit. From what I understand you are trying to achieve (Assigning "a" to the first null element encountered and stop, print all elements in the array) following should work:-

```
public class CheckArrayElementIsNull {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] arr = new String[3];       
     boolean flag=true; //use a flag that will check if null is encountered
     for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if(arr[i] == null && flag) { // first time flag will be true
         arr[i] = "a"; 
         flag=false; //set flag to false , to avoid further assignment of 'a' to null values
        }
        System.out.println(i + "="+ arr[i]);    //print array
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn'T this cause a `NullPointerException` in `System.out.println` if the array contains more than one `null` element?

Comment: @Dragondraikk No it wont , it will simply print null, this is because i am passing an object of `String` type (which has value null) , so the compiler knows which `toString()` method to call. NPE would take place when I would write `System.out.println(null)`, because in this case compiler cannot deduce which `toString()` method to call.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems in your loop.

```
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++) { //<---- This does not iterate over the entire array, leaving out the first and last elements
        if(arr[i] == null) {
            arr[i] = "a"; 
            break; //<---- This terminates the loop entirely, if you want to stop all instructions past this one try using continue instead
        }
        System.out.println(i + "=" + arr[i]);   
        if(arr[i] == null) { //This code is unreachable as arr[i] is initialized if it was detected as null before
            System.out.println(i + "= null");
        }else{
            System.out.println(i + "=" + arr[i]); 
        }
    }
```

Instead you should try

```
 for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == null) {
        arr[i] = "a";
        System.out.println(i + "= null");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(i + "=" + arr[i]); 
}
```

Comment: That will still assign all values in the array to `a`.

Comment: As far as I understand the question that is the desired effect: setting all null-values to "a" instead

Comment: @Stefan not all values, only those with null

Comment: setting the **first** null value found to a in the array.

Comment: @tz reur Oh, only the first? Fixed that :)

Comment: If a value is found to be null, it will break out of loop, and hence will not execute statement `System.out.println(i + "=" + arr[i]);` for further values, Which wont print the entire array (or expected output of the OP with i=1 & i=2 ). Also you are assigning `a` to `arr[i]` and later printing `System.out.println(i + "= null");` which will give value of null although now its value has been set to `a`

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the value at the index you expect not to be `null` before you enter your `for` loop:

```
String[] arr = new String[3];
arr[1] = "a";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  if (arr[i] == null)
  {
    System.out.println(i + "=null");
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println(i + "=" + arr[i]);
  }
}
```